# visual web developer error

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is what I get when I hit F5.... any ideas? I am not sure what is going wrong here at all.

```
Compilation Error
 Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to        service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

 Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:


Line 9:  
Line 10: 
Line 11: public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
Line 12: {
Line 13:     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

 <%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
```

Comment: Not enough information here to help. Are you getting any more errors in the error window?

Comment: List the first (`<% ... %>`) line from the aspx file.

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, `<%@ Page ... Inherits="Default" %>`

does not match with `class _Default`

Change the first line to `<%@ Page ... Inherits="_Default" %>`

Comment: so I changed that and hit F5 again and I get Line 20:             SqlConnection conn = new SqlCommand(sql); Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand' to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: Just change it to connection?

Comment: Congratulations. You solved the initial error and are now facing the next (totally unrelated) error. Research it first and then maybe post a new question.

Comment: You cannot say "SqlConnection conn = new SqlCommand(sql);". Instead wirte: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);.

Comment: thank you @Thomas - maybe you will know this one as well. it is now telling me that the connection string does not exist in the current context?!

Comment: Don't know if you figured it out, but have you set up a SQL server? In that case, save the Connectionstring in your web.config under <connectionStrings>, and get it in the code with ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NAME"].ConnectionString and pass it into the SqlConnection. Create new question if further problems :)